# Unexpected value in Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-module

I have Angular library with providers for url from Angular app.

```
 export class XXXModule {
  static config(SERVER_ADDRESS: string): ModuleWithProviders<any> {
    return {
      ngModule: XXXModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SERVER_ADDRESS,
          useValue: SERVER_ADDRESS
        }
     ]
   }
  }
 }
```

And that library (XXXModule) is imported from lazy loaded module `(DashboardModule)` in Angular app with this

```
export const SERVER_ADDRESS = environment.SERVER_ADDRESS;
imports: [
    XXXModule.config(SERVER_ADDRESS)
]
```

SERVER_ADDRESS is defined in environment file, for production like this

```
  SERVER_ADDRESS: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host
```

Lazy loaded module `(DashboardModule)` is called in app.module.ts file through routes

```
export const AppRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./components/main/main.module').then(
        m => m.DashboardModule
      )
  }
]
```

But, my problem is unexpected value in SERVER_ADDRESS, I got this address in my Angular library.

```
https://test.com/null//null/dynamicExecution/getAll
```

Unexpected part is this `/null//null`

Comment: holy Molly... why aren't you using types?!

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak could you explain better that ?

Answer (score 0):

First using the same value for `provide` and `useValue` properties doesn't make sense. How do you fetch that value later? See [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-an-injectiontoken-object).

Additionally using `window.location` in environment file may cause issues as well. `window` property is not available when angular builds an app.